# FOSOAuthServerBundle and FOSUserbundle

Tags: security, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosoauthserverbundle

I try to use FOSUserBundle and FOSOAuthServerBundle to secure my symfony2 Application. 
I followed documentation, created a client and so an. 
But when I call /oauth/v2/auth I get a Route not found error: 
No route found for "GET /oauth/v2/auth_login"

Can anyone help, what I have missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to do [step 5](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-5-configure-fosoauthserverbundle) and add the routes to your config.yml file:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_oauth_server_token:
    resource: "@FOSOAuthServerBundle/Resources/config/routing/token.xml"

fos_oauth_server_authorize:
    resource: "@FOSOAuthServerBundle/Resources/config/routing/authorize.xml"
```

---

By accessing /oauth/v2/auth_login, you should get:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}
```

This is because you'll need to send a few parameters. Here is an example if you are using a grant type `password`. You'd have to provide the following parameters to your url:

1. your_client_id
2. your_client_secret
3. a_user_username
4. a_user_password

   http://yourWebsite.com/app_dev.php/oauth/v2/token?client_id=your_client_id&client_secret=your_client_secret&grant_type=password&username=a_user_username&password=a_user_password

Comment: I've done step 5 and included the routing. When I look in the symfony2 profiler I can't the any routes matching oauth/v2/auth:login